# 5.26 (Brezis) Prove that $\sqrt{n}u_n\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

5.26 (Brezis) Assume that $(e_n)$ is a orthonormal basis of H.

1. Check that $e_n\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly.

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and set $u_n=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i e_i$.

2. Prove that $|u_n|\rightarrow 0$.
3. Prove that $\sqrt{n}u_n\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly.

**DOUBT:** Items 1 and 2 are OK. However, I'm struggling with item 3.

**MY ATTEMPT:** I know that in this case, $H$ is separable and isomorphic to $\ell^2$ because there is an orthonormal subspace of $H$. And doing some sketches we can find
$$\|\sqrt{n}u_n\|^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_n|^2 \leq M^2$$
where the last inequality is due to item 2. However, I wouldn't prove that $\sqrt{n}u_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ (zero), and why this implies that weak convergence which was required.

Comment: Why don't you try to write down what "pointwise convergence to 0" means?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen If $j$ is fixed, than $(\sqrt{n}u_n, e_j)\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: Yes, from that the pointwise convergence to 0 follows easily just by the fact that $(a_n)$ is bounded. So .....where were you really stuck?

Comment: I would like to understand why this pointwise convergence implies that $\sqrt{n}u_n \rightharpoonup 0$. There are some theorems that guarantee if I have strong convergence then implies weak convergence, but I do not understand why pointwise convergence would imply this weak convergence required?

Comment: And how is this related to $\ell^2$?

Comment: It appears kinda naturally to me but I guess is not really clear to you. To prove that implication, you can either use a the Banach-Agalou-Bourbaki theorem,  or prove it like a simple exercise in real analysis. (I'll post it in another comment)

Comment: Wow, it is starting to become more interesting now. Perfect! I'm waiting.

Comment: For any $v \in l^2$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, you have:$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow +\infty} | \langle u_n,v \rangle | \le \limsup_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{i=0}^m |v_i| | \langle u_n,e_i \rangle |+ | \langle u_n,v_m \rangle | = \limsup_{n \rightarrow +\infty}  | \langle u_n,v_m \rangle |  \le \| u_n \|_2 \|v_m\|_2 \le M \| v_m\|_2$$ where $v_m= v-\sum_{i=0}^m v_ie_i$. Besides, $\lim_{m} \|v_m\|_2=0$, you have the conclusion.

Comment: To be more precise, the first inequality is just simple majoration, the first equality comes from the point wise convergence. The second inequality is just Cauchy-Schwarz. Anyway, Prof. Brezis should have mention this result somewhere in his book.

Comment: ok, perfect!!! Thank you very much for all your explanations.